# autoformatter in eclipse

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, c++11

I´m currently having a hard time with the autoformatter in eclipse...
aiming on my own template for the formatter I´m getting troubles with the line wrapping and it seems that I´m missing any property thread.

The basic configuration works for me but I´m stuck at this, maybe anyone has got a clue where I can find the properties for the code style:

preferred:

```
printf("anything");
```

autoformatter/codestyle currently:

```
printf(
      "anything");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Windows->Preferences->java->code style->formatter`

Here, you can import other formatter, export yours , edit any formatter. Select Edit on current formatter and choose `Line Wrapping` tab.

**EDIT:**
Your problem seems to be related with `Maximum line size`.

Comment: Play with options under "Line Wrapping" tab. There could be few causes.

Comment: Yeah, there may be few. Couldn't tell exactly which one causes such formatting.

Comment: damn it! seems you´ve been right with your guess about the max_line_with. Haven´t considered that, thanks a lot!